# Unable to delegate CPU because of low CPU Staked

Tags: cpu

I wanted to stack some EOS for CPU but cannot do it because of low CPU stacked on my account (currently only 1 EOS staked for CPU).
How am I going to fix it ? I read that I need fast BP for execute transaction with low CPU, but i couldn't find it, I have tried a lot of public node BP.

I am using eosjs library to execute the stacking transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You need someone to pay for the CPU needed to push the transaction.

Use bloks.io with one of the standard wallets. They provide 4 free transactions per user per day.